# ghost, border dragg effect on gwt , gwtquery

Tags: gwt, gwtquery

I'm trying to implement ghost effect on drag operation on gwt, i'm using gwtquery, maybe it also known as border drag effect.. does anyone has an idea to implement it? 
note: i know it can be implemented easyly with jquery but i want to stick with gwt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
DraggableOptions options = new DraggableOptions();
options.setOpacity(0.5);
options.setHelper(HelperType.CLONE);

$("#myWidget").as(Draggable).draggable(options);
```

Comment: you can test without implement it thanks to this example : http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/draggable/demo/DraggableSample2/DraggableSample2.html Just set the Helper type to clone and the opacity to 0.5 and check if it is the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks jdramaix, i haven't try this out, but after i tried the example, i think this is what i'm looking for.